# How to parse json list with nulls in scala?

Tags: json, scala, playframework, scalatest

I am trying to parse json object with a list inside let's say

```
{
   "foo": 12,
   "bar": [ 12, null, null, 32 ]
}
```

In our project we are referring to the scala play documentation and trying to declare a simple json read parser like `Json.reads[MyObject]`

and case class looks like:

```
case class MyObject(
    foo: Int,
    bar: List[Option[Int]]
 )
```

but compiler complains about it:

`Error:(93, 42) No instance of play.api.libs.json.Reads is available for scala.collection.immutable.List[scala.Option[scala.Int]] in the implicit scope (Hint: if declared in the same file, make sure it's declared before)
  implicit val readMyObject = Json.reads[MyObject]`

Anyone knows any workarounds?

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaJsonCombinators

Comment: Did you add the import required for reads as stated in the document you linked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why

```
  implicit def optionReads[T:Reads]: Reads[Option[T]] = (json: JsValue) => json.validateOpt[T]
```

was causing compilation error:

`Error:(11, 73) type mismatch; found : play.api.libs.json.JsValue => play.api.libs.json.JsResult[Option[T]] required: play.api.libs.json.Reads[Option[T]] implicit def optionReads[T:Reads]: Reads[Option[T]] = (json: JsValue) => json.validateOpt[T]`

But I have solved it by adding

```
    implicit def optionFormat[T: Format]: Format[Option[T]] =
      new Format[Option[T]] {
        override def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[Option[T]] =
          json.validateOpt[T]
    }
```

from post [No Json formatter for Option[String]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43031412/no-json-formatter-for-optionstring)

Answer (score 0):

Add `optionReads` method to the object companion.

```
val str = """{
   "foo": 12,
   "bar": [ 12, null, null, 32 ]
}"""

case class MyObject(foo: Int, bar: List[Option[Int]])

object MyObject {

  implicit def optionReads[T:Reads]: Reads[Option[T]] = (json: JsValue) => json.validateOpt[T]

  implicit val reads = Json.reads[MyObject]

}

val json = Json.parse(str)

val obj = Json.fromJson[MyObject](json)

println(obj)
// JsSuccess(MyObject(12,List(Some(12), None, None, Some(32))),)
```

Comment: When I am adding `implicit def optionReads[T:Reads]: Reads[Option[T]] = (json: JsValue) => json.validateOpt[T]` I receive compilation error :(
`Error:(11, 73) type mismatch;
 found   : play.api.libs.json.JsValue => play.api.libs.json.JsResult[Option[T]]
 required: play.api.libs.json.Reads[Option[T]]
  implicit def optionReads[T:Reads]: Reads[Option[T]] = (json: JsValue) => json.validateOpt[T]`

Comment: Could there be a problem with scala version I am using? `2.11.12`

Comment: Maybe, I am using 2.12.6. I'm going to check with 2.11.12 version.